# Entity Framework virtual properties conflict

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I can't understand why this works everywhere, but in this spot.

```
private usersliked createUserLiked(post post)
    {
        usersliked newUsersLiked = db.usersliked.Create();
        newUsersLiked.postId = post.idpost;
        int length = db.user.Count();
        user user = db.user.OrderBy(c => c.iduser).Skip(randomizer.Next(1, length)).FirstOrDefault();
        newUsersLiked.userId = user.iduser;
        db.usersliked.Add(newUsersLiked);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newUsersLiked; 
    }
```

I want to add new `userLiked` record, that has some foreign keys to `post` and `user`. Virtual class of foreign key for `user` is created by `EF` after `idUser` is added. But using the same method to link `post` doesn't work! And, since "post" graph in table is not null, it gives me an error. As you see on screenshot, it's virtual class is null. Why?

[image]

UPDATE:
If i manually set post, then it messes up `user` link. Somehow it copies postId to userId, and everything brakes.

[image]

UPDATE:
Problem is solved. It was a mistake in foreign keys, they referenced one common item.

Comment: is the `post` being passed into `createUserLiked(post post)` `null`?

Comment: @DFord No, newUserLiked.postId, that was taken from post.Idpost is not null as you can see. And here is screenshot : http://img42.com/LI76o+

Comment: does `newUserLiked.post = post;` work?

Comment: @DFord Yes, but in that case user doesn't work : http://img42.com/shb1j+

Comment: @DFord And i don't have user with userId=30. It took it from postId i suppose.

Comment: What gets returned when you query for `user`

Comment: @DFord it returns user, that exist, with nice id, but after db.userLiked.Add() it copies id from post to userLiked.userId. I'll add screenshots in next comment.

Comment: @DFord http://img42.com/bE0lT+ Here it is.